# Opencart. Как разбить в шапке количество и сумму товаров?

Tags: php, opencart

По стандарту в опенкарте корзина в шапке отображается так: 49 item(s) - 11,124.00 . Мне нужно чтобы отображалась только сумма: 11,124.00 .

Пытался править языковой файл ($_['text_items'] = '%s item(s) - %s';) , всё было отлично до того момента, пока не нажмешь на добавление товара в корзину. После нажатия на кнопку, надпись становится прежнего вида. Как сделать так, чтобы всегда отображалась только сумма товара ? Или же как разбить это на 2 переменные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать отображение **суммы заказа** вместо количество + сумма нужно:

1. В `language/russian/module/cart.php` заменить стандартный `text_items` на:

```html
$_['text_items'] = 'Корзина: %s';
```

2. В `controller/module/cart.php` найти строку с `text_items` и заменить на:

```html
$this->data['text_items'] = sprintf($this->language>get('text_items'), $this->currency->format($total));
```

3. В `view/...../module/cart.tpl` найти `div heading` и заменить его на:

```html
<div class="heading">
    <a title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>"><span id="cart-           total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></a>
  </div>
```